# Rails wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when passing no arguments to custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I promise i've looked through all the similar answers, but I'm new to Rails and just have no idea what I'm doing.  Anyway...

I have a `UsersController` with a method `customer`.  I don't know if this method works or not, I haven't made it far enough to see what errors pop up.

```
64     def customer
65        begin
66          customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("hardcodedidfornow")
67        rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
68          status 402
69          return "Error retrieving customer: #{e.message}"
70        end
71      status 200
72      content_type :json
73      customer.to_json
74    end
```

I defined that method in my routes as such

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy] do 
        member do
          get :customer
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Then I call it from my iOS app with GET at this route and no extra parameters

```
http://baseurl.com/api/v1/users/theuserid/customer
```

And I always get internal server error 500 and when I check the logs it says wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).

```
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#customer as JSON
2016-10-07T05:04:59.087546+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/v1/users/5/customer" for 162.237.102.13 at 2016-10-07 05:04:59 +0000
2016-10-07T05:04:59.135976+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "user"=>{}}
2016-10-07T05:04:59.568989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/users/5/customer" host=someapp.herokuapp.com request_id=7f0f76bd-4577-40b0-9eb6-265787cf3d5c fwd="162.237.102.13" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=496ms status=500 bytes=259
2016-10-07T05:04:59.578541+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-07T05:04:59.577583+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 441ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
2016-10-07T05:04:59.578543+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
2016-10-07T05:04:59.578544+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:71:in `customer'
```

So I guess I'm looking for a solution but also an understanding of where i've gone wrong so I can handle this better in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: there is an error in customer method. Please post full method.

Comment: @Dinesh thanks for the hint, I would have never guessed.  Unfortunately I don't know if my `customer` method works or not.

Comment: I see one method that is called with one arguments: `customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("hardcodedidfornow")` => then the issue is probably there. please check the definition of `Customer.retrieve`  to see if really accepts 1 argument.

Comment: ..or just say us where is line 71 of the code you posted ;-)

Comment: Is there a `status` method in the controller?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No there's not!  I had paraphrased my method from a tutorial without fully understanding it.  I will make a change there and let you know!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev really this question was about me not being able to interpret the error logs correctly.  Your suggestion helped me solve my issue and it's working great now.  If you rephrase your comment into an appropriate answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nah, it's not a real answer :)